# How to handle an exception in a Django Middleware?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, middleware

I have a problem with proper handling an exception in Django middleware.
My exception:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException
from rest_framework.status import HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
class MyProfileAuthorizationError(APIException):    
    def __init__(self, msg):
        APIException.__init__(self, msg)
        self.status_code = HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
        self.message = msg
```

And my Middleware:

```
class PatchRequestUserWithProfile:
def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response

def __call__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    patch_request_for_nonanon_user(request)
    if not request.user.profile:
        raise MyProfileAuthorizationError("You are not allowed to use this profile.")

    response = self.get_response(request)
    return response
```

And this exception throws 500 instead of 403. How can i fix that?

Comment: can you add the error traceback?

Comment: MyProfileAuthorizationError this returns 500 ?

Comment: @gachdavit yes, it is. Looks like it is not handled as a http exception, but like usual error raising.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to return a [**`HttpResponseForbidden`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseForbidden) response instead of raising exception

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden


class PatchRequestUserWithProfile:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        patch_request_for_nonanon_user(request)
        if not request.user.profile:
            return HttpResponseForbidden("You are not allowed to use this profile.")

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

Comment: Boom! That's it! Thanks a lot! I have also tried to return a response, but was not aware about existence of HttpResponseForbidden.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Middleware, I think you should use [`permissions`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/):

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class CustomAccessPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = 'You are not allowed to use this profile.'

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
       if not request.user.profile:
           return False
       return True
```

And add this in [`DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy) to make it available for every API view.

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
   'path.to.CustomAccessPermission',
)
```

Comment: no, if I call super here - it does not return anything, I have tested that - no any response from application returns.

Comment: sorry, what did you mean by `it does not return anything`?

Comment: it means that I don't get any response from the application in that case - it handles

Comment: but in that case I have to assign this permission to all my viewsets in the whole my project?

Comment: no, it will be added to all viewsets. If you want some viewsets to have different behaviour, then you need to override their `permission_classes` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this exception:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException

class MyProfileAuthorizationError(APIException):
    status_code = 403
    default_detail = 'You are not allowed to use this profile'
    default_code = 'forbidden'
```

I think you can't do that, read this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/-ncPqVzF8W8

Comment: The same problem remains - got 500 instead of 403